# How is delegation applied here?

Tags: java, algorithm, analysis

Would someone be able to explain how the delegation pattern is applied to the following code?
I understand that it  allows object composition to achieve the same code reuse as inheritance, but I've trouble understanding it with the code example.

```
    brightness_4
// Java program to illustrate 
// delegation 
class RealPrinter { 
    // the "delegate" 
    void print() 
    { 
        System.out.println("The Delegate"); 
    } 
} 
  
class Printer { 
    // the "delegator" 
    RealPrinter p = new RealPrinter(); 
  
    // create the delegate 
    void print() 
    { 
        p.print(); // delegation 
    } 
} 
  
public class Tester { 
  
    // To the outside world it looks like Printer actually prints. 
public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Printer printer = new Printer(); 
        printer.print(); 
    } 
} `enter code here`
```

Comment: I think I'd explain it as using an existing data structure (ArrayList) as a delegate in order to implement a Stack interface. You could implement stack behaviour from scratch with whatever properties work for you, but by delegating to an instance of an existing class (which doesn't provide the Stack interface that you want to expose) you save an awful lot of work - great reuse.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forwarding_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Stack` class instantiates a variable from the `ArrayList` class (`list`), when you call methods on `list` you're delegating to the `ArrayList` class.

> Delegation means that you use an object of another class as an
> instance variable, and forward messages to the instance.
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delegation-vs-inheritance-java/

You are using methods from the `ArrayList` class for your `Stack` class. When other classes use the `Stack` class, they will think that the operations are handled by the `Stack` class. Outsiders do not know that the `Stack` class is actually passing the instruction on to the `ArrayList` class.